# Connection URL param "currentSchema" is not respected .. until it is

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

We have a JHipster based app (Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA.. nothing exotic) with a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` configured as

`jdbc:postgresql://primary.db.my.org:5432/dbName?currentSchema=schemaA,schemaB`

(the user used for connection, owns schemaA)

We have an app working like this for a year without any issues, but recently it started to suffer from the following syndrome: when the app starts, this parameter seems to be ignored for about half an hour - requests to unqualified tables from schemaB (which is not owned by the user) end up with Relation not found.

after about 30 minutes, it all of a sudden works fine again.

any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there was a problem with Liquibase, which was solved by this PR: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/1864

Morale: always check all possible paths that could be causing the issue..

In fact this solution was occasionally found by the other guy in our team who happened to run the app without all necessary settings, then just provided separate value for "spring.liquibase.url".. which is most likely how it should have been done in the first place..